# Greek letters in MySQL don't saved properly

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I try to save some Greek letter in MySQL with PHP but the characters are saved like this: "Î¼Î±ÏÏ„Î¯Î¿Ï"

On my HTML page i have se meta charset on "utf8" and also I have create the db in MySQL like this "....CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci". Please find below my php db connetction code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","customers" );

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
mysql_query('set character set UTF8');
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
}
```

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through/279279#279279

Comment: Oh - then again; you're mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli_` extensions; those `mysql_query` statements won't work with the `mysqli_connect` so the database connector charset isn't being set.

Comment: Thank you for noticing that mysql_ and mysqli are together! I simply add "mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");" and it worked!

Comment: Glad you managed to sort it - it's often better that way, you're more likely to remember it now ;)